Muti-tenancy when using Policy Enforcer with Quarkus and Keycloak
I’m implementing multi-tenancy on an API server using Keycloak and Quarkus, with Policy Enforcer for authorization, and I need to dynamically switch the OIDC tenant configuration based on the incoming request.
Here is the code I’ve implemented for dynamic tenant resolution:
@ApplicationScoped
public class CustomTenantResolver implements TenantConfigResolver {

    @Override
    public Uni<OidcTenantConfig> resolve(RoutingContext context, OidcRequestContext<OidcTenantConfig> requestContext) {
        // Extract the tenant name dynamically from the URL path.
        String path = context.request().path();

        // Extract the tenant name assuming the URL structure is /tenant-name/other-path
        String[] pathParts = path.split("/");
        String tenantName = (pathParts.length > 1) ? pathParts[1] : null;

        if (tenantName != null) {
            // Dynamically configure the OidcTenantConfig based on the extracted tenant name
            String keycloakUrl = ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue("keycloak.url", String.class);

            OidcTenantConfig config = new OidcTenantConfig();
            config.setTenantId(tenantName);  // Use tenant name from URL
            config.setAuthServerUrl(keycloakUrl + "/realms/" + tenantName);  // Use the tenant name as the realm name
            config.setClientId("document-vault");
            config.getCredentials().setSecret("secret");
            config.setApplicationType(ApplicationType.HYBRID);

            return Uni.createFrom().item(config);
        } else {
            // If no tenant name is found in the URL, set to default tenant
            context.put(OidcUtils.TENANT_ID_ATTRIBUTE, OidcUtils.DEFAULT_TENANT_ID);
            return Uni.createFrom().nullItem();
        }
    }
}

This works as expected for OIDC tenant resolution. Below is the default tenant configuration in application.properties:
# Default tenant Configuration
keycloak.url=http://localhost:8080
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=${keycloak.url}/realms/default
quarkus.oidc.client-id=document-vault
quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=secret
quarkus.oidc.token.issuer=any

# Enable Policy Enforcement
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enable=true
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.lazy-load-paths=false

When I call the resource server, e.g., /tenant-2/api/users/bearer, I can see in the debug logs that it switches to tenant-2 for loading the OIDC config:
[io.qua.oid.run.OidcAuthenticationMechanism] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-3) Resolved OIDC tenant id: tenant-2
[io.qua.oid.run.BearerAuthenticationMechanism] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-3) Starting a bearer access token authentication
[io.qua.oid.run.OidcUtils] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-3) Looking for a token in the authorization header
[io.qua.oid.run.OidcIdentityProvider] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-3) Starting creating SecurityIdentity
[io.qua.oid.run.OidcProviderClient] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-3) Get verification JWT Key Set at http://localhost:8080/realms/tenant-2/protocol/openid-connect/certs

However, the authorization request to Keycloak is always sent to the default auth server:
DEBUG [org.apa.htt.imp.con.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] (vert.x-worker-thread-1) http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
DEBUG [org.apa.htt.imp.exe.MainClientExec] (vert.x-worker-thread-1) Executing request GET /realms/default/authz/protection/resource_set?matchingUri=true&deep=true&max=-1&exactName=false&uri=%2Ftenant-2%2Fapi%2Fusers%2Fbearer HTTP/1.1

According to the Quarkus documentation, it’s possible to change the policy enforcer dynamically (Quarkus Keycloak Authorization Guide), but it doesn’t mention how to change the OIDC configuration dynamically.
How can I dynamically switch the OIDC configuration (auth server URL, client ID, etc.) in this setup to match the tenant being resolved?
